# Hierarchy viewer not working with HTC Sensation

Tags: android, hierarchy, viewer

I have htc desire and hierarchy viewer works fine. But when I plug the sensation than nothing happens I have refresh button but afrer clicking on it nothing happens :(

where is the problem ?

Answer (score 2):

Hierarchy View normally does not support hardware, only the emulator. For API Level 12 devices and higher, you can try embedding [`ViewServer`](https://github.com/romainguy/ViewServer) into your app, though I have not yet tried this. It is also possible that you might have better results with a rooted device, though I have not tried that either.

Comment: what  'normally' means ?, I have htc desire that works fine with hierarchy viewer. But I do not get why is that, my desire have 2.1 and my sensation 2.3 is that the problem ? ( i think it should not be problem). And about routing that makes sense cause my desire is routed and sensation is not, is there place where I can read more about this ?, Thanks

Comment: @Luk: "what 'normally' means ?" -- "normally" means a non-rooted device with an app without `ViewServer`. "that the problem ?" -- no, your use of hardware is the problem. "is there place where I can read more about this ?" -- quite possibly, but I would have no idea where.

Comment: @CommonsWare Interesting… Do you mean that using hierarchyviewer with hardware is not recommended? One should rather use the emulator to examinate the layouts? If that is the case, could you elaborate or point out some documentation about that?

Comment: @Renaud: "Do you mean that using hierarchyviewer with hardware is not recommended?" -- it simply does not work, unless you have installed a "userdebug" firmware on your device. "One should rather use the emulator to examinate the layouts?" -- that is the simplest solution in most cases. "If that is the case, could you elaborate or point out some documentation about that?" -- http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/debugging-ui.html