# Examining the Android View Hierarchy at Runtime in Debug mode?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm in an activity and I can't find a particular view. ie findViewById(R.layout.someId) is returning null.  So I would just like to see for the current activity what the actual view hierarchy is at runtime.  How can I do this?

Comment: maybe R.layout.someId should be changed to R.id.someId ?

Comment: perhaps but the main point of the question is to be able to view the hierachy that is there.  Whatever it is.

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PAgE7saQUUY&feature=plcp

Comment: Please include this in your answser.

Comment: If you mean the tool Hierarchy Viewer, it's supposed not to work with all devices, but it always works fine with the emulator.
Please, read [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7320060/397244).

Comment: Alright, I did. Seems like it helped you. Thanks for the checkmark and upvote.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I believe `findViewById` requires a parameter of `R.id.someid` and it cannot take layouts. For a layout you must use `setContentView(R.layout.someId);`

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PAgE7saQUUY

Comment: I am looking to be able to view the hierarchy at runtime.

Comment: Works for me.
From android dev "using findViewById(int) to retrieve the widgets"
A view/layout is not a widget.

Answer (score 2):

This perfectly well-worded question has been down-voted for reasons I cannot understand.

And the perfectly straightforward answer:

***Yes, you can use the SDK HierarchyViewer tool to see your whole layout tree at runtime***

is hidden behind a youtube link that keeps getting poked into answers that say something else or comments to the original question.

Here's a link to the current documentation for HV:
https://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-ui.html

Note that the YouTube video says this can only be used with the app running in the emulator but the documentation says it will also work on "devices running a developer version of the Android system." I certainly don't run my own Android phone, which I use for most of my dev testing, with a dev version of the OS, so I think the YouTube video is effectively correct if not technically correct.